# fading external images in an array

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

I am trying to take ten images, load them into an array, and then show them one at a time,fading out each one in turn.  I keep getting this error.

ReferenceError: Error #1056: Cannot create property alpha on String.
    at fl.transitions::Tween/setPosition()
    at fl.transitions::Tween/set position()
    at fl.transitions::Tween()
    at images_fla::MainTimeline/goPlay()

my code

```
import fl.transitions.Tween;
import fl.transitions.easing.*;

play_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, goPlay)

var images = new Array();

images[0] = "1.jpg";
images[1] = "2.jpg";
images[2] = "3.jpg";
images[3] = "4.jpg";
images[4] = "5.jpg";
images[5] = "6.jpg";
images[6] = "7.jpg";
images[7] = "8.jpg";
images[8] = "9.jpg";
images[9] = "10.jpg";

function goPlay(e:MouseEvent) {
    for (var i:int = 0; i <10; i++) {
    loadWindow.source = images[i];
    var myTween:Tween = new Tween(images[i], "alpha", None.easeOut, 1, 0, 15, true);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first parameter of the Tween object is a string, and fails because strings don't have an `alpha` property. Try passing the actual `loadWindow` object instead of the `images[i]`.

Answer (score 2):

your problem is all you have is an array of strings, your file names. So when you are trying to target images[i] you are telling the tween to do something to a string which it can't do. You have to load the image into a loader and then apply that tween to the loader.
[Loader example](http://www.republicofcode.com/tutorials/flash/as3loader/)